# How do i write in integral form this definition

Tags: probability, statistics

Hi i was reading the definition of  average observed probability
$$p^{obs}_{avg}(p)= E_{x \sim F_x } [F_{Y|x}(\hat Q_p(x))]  \quad \forall \ p \in [0,1] $$

where $\hat Q_p$ is the p-th quantile and $F_{y|x}$ is the cdf predicted fro the input x.  the author says that this is the probability of observing the target below the quantile prediction, averaged over $F_X$.

does the tilde means that the argument is distributed according to $F_x$ and that this is another way to say that the average is over the elements of the dataset?
like
$$p^{obs}_{avg}(p)= \int{F_{Y|x}(\hat Q_p(x)) F_x(x)} dx $$

with x that vary both in $F_x(x)$ and $Q_p(x)$ over all the test dataset?